# Is there anyway to use Jquery in React component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I know the correct way is never to use jquery with ReactJS. I am just starting react and need to finish my website in a short amount of time. Here is the Url : http://kyloxue.design/#/DesignHome?_k=311rh4
I am using react to construct the whole layout.
when you first visit the page, all the images are in one line, what I want is to use Jquery to slice every 3 images into a column. However, it doesnt work unless you click the page twice (click on the "design" button on the left side).

Following are my code for the gallery page :

```
export class Gallery extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
   {/* *****************jquery slice image ******************  */}
    var $vw = $('.wrapper').height();
    var $imageEach = $('.image-grid-each');
    var $myimage = $('.image-grid-each img');
    var $imageW = $(".image-grid-image").width();
    var $imageH = $(".image-grid-image").height();
    for (var i = 0; i < $imageEach.length; i += 3) {
            $imageEach.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='image-grid-slice'></div>");

        }
 {/* *****************jquery slice image ******************  */}
    this.props.loadImages();
  }


 handleThumbClick(selectedImage) {
   this.setState({
     selectedImage
   })
 }

render(){
const {images, selectedImage, selectImage} = this.props;
return (
  <div >
    <SkyLight hideOnOverlayClicked ref="simpleDialog">
            <img className="modalPhoto" src={selectedImage} />
    </SkyLight>

    <div className="flex-box">
      {images.map((image, index) => (
         <div key={index} onClick={() => {selectImage(image); this.refs.simpleDialog.show()}} className="image-grid-each">
                 <img className="image-grid-image" src={image}/>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
 }
}

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
    images: state.images,
    selectedImage: state.selectedImage
  }
 }

function mapActionCreatorsToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(GalleryActions, dispatch);
}
```

Things that really matter are divided ****. Basically I just wrap my jquery code to be in the componentdidMount. I dont know how to manipulate the css styling using React. Jquery seems like a quick fix. So is there anyway that I can make it work when not working in a DOM environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. jQuery actually works in my code. I use the incorrect Component Life cycle. It should be ComponentDidUpdate instead of ComponentDidMount.